# WebHDFS append endpoint not behaving as documented

Tags: webhdfs

I'm following [this documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html#Append_to_a_File) about my version of webHDFS (2.6), and trying to append to a file in the system that already exists.

The issue that's confusing me is that the docs say I will receive a redirect to the appropriate datanode after doing the initial POST, however I'm actually getting a 200, and whatever data I pass in the body is being correctly appended on the first request.

```
$ curl -i -X POST "http://localhost:50075/webhdfs/v1/user/d1/c7/d1c78e73d6734c71abb055667abca170?op=APPEND&namenoderpcaddress=localhost:9000&user.name=zach"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 06 Mar 2015 17:54:26 GMT
Date: Fri, 06 Mar 2015 17:54:26 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 06 Mar 2015 17:54:26 GMT
Date: Fri, 06 Mar 2015 17:54:26 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 0
Server: Jetty(6.1.26)
```

This is all great if I just have to make one request, but I want to make sure this will work in other hadoop environments, and it's concerning me that I'm not getting the 307 response promised in the docs. I'm running in distributed mode (albeit just on my local machine). Anyone run into this before?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the noise, just realized I was talking to webHDFS running on the data node, not the namenode, and since it's the same API call for both, I was really just doing the second request and it always worked since I have only one data node.